# Converting Date in excel with Ordinal Notation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ordinal

Using excel 2016, tried every formula and macros I could find, but it still doesn't work.

I have a date format

11.11.2020 11:09:18

I need it to be like this

Nov 11th, 2020 , 11:09 AM

The main problem is with ending after date: 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th etc.

P.s. each date is in one cell

Maybe somebody had a similar problem and managed to solve it.

Comment: Is your source data format ***mm.dd.yyyy*** or ***dd.mm.yyyy*** ???

Comment: dd.mm.yyyy

oh, sorry, should have made a better example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following:

Formula in `B1`:

```
=TEXT(A1,"[$-409]mmm d")&IFERROR(INDEX({"st","nd","rd"},ROUNDUP(MATCH(DAY(A1),{1,21,31,2,22,32,3,23},0)/3,0)),"th")&TEXT(A1," yyyy hh:mm AM/PM")
```

And if you want the commas in there as well:

Formula in `C1`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A1,"[$-409]mmm d, yyyy, hh:mm AM/PM"),",",IFERROR(INDEX({"st,","nd,","rd,"},ROUNDUP(MATCH(DAY(A1),{1,21,31,2,22,32,3,23},0)/3,0)),"th,"),1)
```

[image]

Mind you, this transform a data into text!

Comment: This is beautiful!

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you very much! You have saved my day! :D